# Rails Image Tag Doesn't Work Unless an HTML Element Present

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a _header partial that renders with every page in my Rails app. However the image in this partial does not show up unless there is another HTML element present.

For Example:
My login page has nothing but a background image. The header picture will not show up here. 
If I add a simple `<p></p>` with nothing inside the image renders.

On other pages as long as an HTML element is present, the image will show. When the page is blank no image renders.

---

This is the _header partial call for an image:

```
 <%= image_tag("assets/headerpicture.png", :class => "headerpicture") %>
```

The server log shows the _header partial is being called:

```
Started GET "/login" for 74.197.92.5 at 2016-06-16 20:06:43 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 256ms (Views: 254.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

**Update**
When using a DOM inspector to see view the webpage, the picture is listed as an HTML element:

```
     <header>
     <img alt="nothing" class="headerpicture" src="/assets/headerpicture-7a1f47b42f3c6edb5a5220b111160f94564ccc19b196f1d5ebc1970ce4be6793.png">
     </header>
```

**the temporary fix I'm currently using is just adding an empty div of height/width 1px to the page. But I want to understand why this is occurring**

Comment: if you open up the console, is it present in the node list on the dom? it might be rendering but the container its in has a height set to 0

Comment: If you look in the element inspector on a blank page do you see the element in the dom?

Comment: The code for the Image is exactly as above, it's not inside of any divs. In fact the _header partial has nothing but that line of code to render the image